# Uso della parola "consultazione"

Tags: word-usage

Ho un dubbio riguardo all'uso della parola "consultazione". Ho letto nel dizionario che opere come, ad esempio, vocabolari, dizionari, enciclopedie, atlanti, guide... si possono chiamare "opere di consultazione". Non sono sicura, però, che l'uso della parola "consultazione" in questa frase sia corretto:

> A casa ho un libro di grammatica italiana per studenti stranieri che
>   uso per *consultazione* quando ho dei dubbi.

Potreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo?

Comment: Sono perplesso sulla correzione di “riguardo a” in “riguardo”: ho posto una [domanda a questo proposito](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2296/riguardo-o-riguardo-a).

Comment: È [riguardo a](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/riguardo-a-o-riguardo_(La_grammatica_italiana)/) («_La forma senza la preposizione `a`, anche se molto diffusa, è scorretta_») :-) Mi sono permesso di rollbackare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“Consultazione” come atto del consultare è un [termine normalissimo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/consultazione/), in tutti i sensi del “consultare” (un libro, un medico, i partiti per formare un governo etc.). Nel caso specifico di quella frase si vuole sottolineare che la grammatica in questione non viene tenuta per leggerla da cima a fondo (o per farne la base per un corso etc.), ma appunto per cercarvi qualcosa di specifico in caso di bisogno.
E “opere di consultazione” è un termine standard di qualsiasi biblioteca o libreria (persino [Amazon](http://www.amazon.it/b?node=508864031)!)

Comment: Come detto nella mia risposta, "consultazione" è un termine normalissimo, ma quella frase suona molto male alle mie orecchie. Nessuno avrebbe problemi a capirla, ma decisamente sembrerebbe quasi "pretenzionsa". Per quanto riguarda opere di consultazione, al di fuori del contesto di una biblioteca non è un termine particolarmente utilizzato.

Comment: Se suoni “pretenzioso” o meno probabilmente dipende dalla propria esperienza. A me non suona affatto così e, se proprio vogliamo connotarla in qualche modo, potrebbe avere una sfumatura vagamente professionale, da parte di chi (come è evidentemente l'autore della frase sulla grammatica) è abituato a parlare di libri di vari tipi e con vari possibili usi. O forse sono io che frequento troppe librerie e biblioteche. :-)

Comment: sicuramente è tutto relativo. Tuttavia sentendo quella frase detta da una persona non di madrelingua mi verrebbe se non altro da sorridere.

Answer (score 1):

Sebbene non ci siano dubbi sul significato della frase, l'utilizzo di *consultazione* in questo caso suona piuttosto strano.

Io direi invece:

> Ho un libro di grammatica che consulto quando ho dei dubbi.

A parte nell'espressione (che non penso sia veramente molto usata) "opere di consultazione", [il dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/consultazione/) riporta anche altri usi, come ad esempio quello di "visita" di un medico/avvocato/etc.

> consultazioni ogni giorno dalle quattro alle sei.

Comment: It is considered polite to comment if you downvote...