# “Riguardo” o “riguardo a”?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Nel testo di [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/uso-della-parola-consultazione) qualcuno ha corretto le parole “Ho un dubbio riguardo all'uso della parola...” in “Ho un dubbio riguardo l'uso della parola...” commentando “riguardo all'uso is sloppy italian”.

Controllando sul [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riguardo/), vedo che questo presunto “sloppy italian” è lì pienamente avallato (“*riguardo a*, in relazione a, in quanto a, com. soprattutto nell’uso burocr. e comm.: *riguardo alla vostra richiesta dobbiamo rispondere negativamente*”). Ma in effetti la situazione è strana: “riguardo (a)” è tecnicamente un sostantivo, usato in questo tipo di frase come se fosse una sorta di locuzione preposizionale, forse come forma ellittica di “con riguardo a” o simili. Come stanno veramente le cose?

Comment: È [riguardo a](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/riguardo-a-o-riguardo_(La_grammatica_italiana)/) («_La forma senza la preposizione `a`, anche se molto diffusa, è scorretta_») :-) Mi sono permesso di rollbackare.

Comment: Era una mia domanda e anch'io ho avuto il dubbio su quale fosse la forma corretta.

Comment: Credo che la risposta sia almeno parzialmente contenuta nella domanda stessa: anche per me si tratta di una locuzione prepositiva, cioè di una locuzione che ha funzione di preposizione. La stessa logica segue la locuzione "_rispetto a_". Va considerato che "_riguardare_" è un verbo in uso da sempre in italiano, lo usava anche Dante. Forse va anche considerata come locuzione polirematica.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Secondo la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/riguardo-a-o-riguardo_(La_grammatica_italiana)/), la forma corretta è "*riguardo a*", la «forma senza la preposizione *a*, anche se molto diffusa, è scorretta».

Il verbo *riguardare* significa *guardare di nuovo*, nel senso di dedicare particolare attenzione a qualcosa o qualcuno. Ha lo stesso significato e la stessa costruzione del verbo *rispettare*, da *respicĕre*, *guardare indietro, tornare a guardare*.

Si tratta di un vocabolo antichissimo entrato fin da subito nel lessico cortese/cavalleresco. Nei suoi vari significati compare ben 55 volte nella sola *Divina Commedia*, 149 volte nel *Decameron*, 49 volte nell'*Orlando Furioso* (curiosamente è del tutto assente dal *Canzoniere*!).

Il riguardo *si ha*, *si porta*, a qualcosa/qualcuno.

In italiano antico si diceva *avendo riguardo a* per introdurre una proposizione parentetica spesso modale o causale.

Così compare ad esempio nel Decameron, in alcune indimenticabili scene erotiche boccacciane:

> «La giovane, che non era di ferro né di diamante, assai agevolmente si piegò a’ piaceri dell’abate: il quale, abbracciatala e basciatala più volte, in su il letticello del monaco salitosene, **avendo forse riguardo al grave peso della sua dignità e alla tenera età della giovane**, temendo forse di non offenderla per troppa gravezza, non sopra il petto di lei salì ma lei sopra il suo petto pose, e per lungo spazio con lei si trastullò».
>
> «Alessandro, quantunque non la conoscesse, **avendo riguardo alla compagnia che ella avea**, lei stimò dovere essere nobile e ricca, e bellissima la vedea: per che senza troppo lungo pensiero rispose che, se questo a lei piacea, a lui era molto a grado. Essa allora levatasi a sedere in su il letto, davanti a una tavoletta dove Nostro Signore era effigiato postogli in mano uno anello, gli si fece sposare; e appresso insieme abbracciatisi, con gran piacer di ciascuna delle parti quanto di quella notte restava si sollazzarono»
>
> «Il famigliar d’Osbech, il cui nome era Antioco, a cui la bella donna era a guardia rimasa, ancora che attempato fosse, veggendola così bella, senza servare al suo amico e signor fede di lei s’innamorò: e sappiendo la lingua di lei (il che molto a grado l’era, sì come a colei alla quale parecchi anni a guisa quasi di sorda e di mutola era convenuta vivere, per lo non aver persona inteso né essa essere stata intesa da persona), da amore incitato cominciò seco tanta familiarità a pigliare in pochi dì, che non dopo molto, **non avendo riguardo al signor loro che in arme e in guerra era**, fecero la dimestichezza non solamente amichevole ma amorosa divenire, l’uno dell’altro pigliando sotto le lenzuola maraviglioso piacere»
>
> «Ora avvenne, dopo certo spazio di tempo, che la fortuna apparecchiò caso da poter lo scolare al suo disiderio sodisfare; per ciò che, essendosi il giovane che dalla vedova era amato, **non avendo alcun riguardo allo amor da lei portatogli**, innamorato d’un’altra donna e non volendo né poco né molto dire né fare cosa che a lei fosse a piacere, essa in lagrime e in amaritudine si consumava»

Nei contesti citati su, *aver riguardo* significa propriamente *portare rispetto*. Ma è già presente in Boccaccio quell'uso di *avendo riguardo a* che poi in italiano moderno sarebbe diventato *riguardo a*. Eccone un esempio:

> «Niuna cosa mi poté mai far credere, avendo riguardo a’ vostri costumi, che altro mi dovesse seguir della mia venuta che quello che io veggio che voi ne fate; di che io vi sarò sempre obligata.»

Qui *avendo riguardo a* può essere anche visto come locuzione prepositiva che introduce un complemento di argomento.

Da notare che, sempre nel Decameron, si trova anche la locuzione *avendo rispetto a* nel senso di *rispetto a*:

> «Venuta la fine della lunga novella d’Emilia, non per ciò dispiaciuta a alcuno per la sua lunghezza, ma da tutti tenuto che brievemente narrata fosse stata **avendo rispetto alla quantità e alla varietà de’ casi in essa raccontati**, per che la reina, alla Lauretta con un sol cenno mostrato il suo disio, le diè cagione di così cominciare».